# find $P(X>Y)$ in $f(x; y) = \frac67(x^2 − y^2) $; $x > 0$; $ y < 1$

Tags: probability, statistics, multivariable-calculus, probability-distributions, definite-integrals

find $P(X>Y)$ in $f(x; y) = \frac67(x^2 − y^2) $; $x > 0$; $ y < 1$

I am aware this can be solved with a double integral, such that:

$$ P(X>Y)=\int\int\frac67(x^2 − y^2) dydx$$

However, I do not know **how to set the boundaries?**

$$ P(X>Y)=\int_\infty^0\int_{\infty}^x\frac67(x^2 − y^2) dydx$$

**What is the solution to**  $P(X>Y)$ ?

Answer (score 2):

You have to see how the set $\{ (x,y): x>y \}$ intersects with $\{(x,y): x>0, y<1  \}$. The intersection can be written as:

$D_1\sqcup D_2$, where  $D_1:= \{ (x,y): x>y, 0<x<1, y<1\}$  and $D_2:=\{ (x,y): x\geq 1, y<1  \}$.

By additivity you then have to calculate:

$\int_{D_1}f(x,y)dydx+ \int_{D_2}f(x,y)dydx$

Notice that for a rectangle $D=\{ (x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2: a\leq x\leq b, c\leq y \leq d   \}$, we have:

$\int_D f(x,y)dx dy= \int_a^b \Big( \int_c^d f(x,y) dy \Big) dx= \int_c^d \Big( \int_a^b f(x,y) dx \Big) dy$

In our case:

$\int_{D_2} f(x,y)dx dy= \int_1^\infty \Big( \int_{-\infty}^1 f(x,y) dy \Big) dx$

And for a set $C=\{ (x,y)\in \mathbb{R}^2: a\leq x\leq b, g_1(x) \leq y\leq g_2(x) \}$, where $g_1,g_2$ are functions of $x$, we have:

$\int_Cf(x,y)dxdy= \int_a^b \Big( \int_{g_1(x)}^{g_2(x)} f(x,y)dy \Big)dx$

In our case:

$\int_{D_1}f(x,y)dydx = \int_0^1 \Big( \int_{-\infty}^x f(x,y) dy \Big)dx$

I decomposed the  intersection to sets such that the upper bound is a constant and explicit function on them. Were you to impose more conditions, say for example $Y<-X+3$ and $Y>-100$, then I would have to consider the set:

$\{ (x,y): x<y, x>0 , y<1, y<-x+3, y>-100  \}$

And decompose them into sets where the upper bound and lower bounds are constant functions. Which observing this set in $\mathbb{R}^2$ would give me a natural  decomposition looking at the set with respect to the '$x$' axis:

$E_1:= \{ (x,y): 0<x<1, -100<y<x \}$, $E_2:=\{ (x,y): 1 \leq x \leq 2, -100<y<1 \}$ and $E_3:=\{ (x,y): 2<x<103, -100<y<-x+3 \}$

And summed the integrals on each set.

Comment: @could you elaborate your answer? I, unfortunately, do not know how to find boundaries for $D_1$ and/or $D_2$. I am not familiar with the notations you used to describe the sets

Comment: Do you see that $D_2$ is a 'rectangle' in $\mathbb{R}^2$?

Comment: no, not really. R^2 denotes the proportion of variance in the response variable explained by the independent variables, right?

Comment: No, $\mathbb{R}^2$ is the real plane. Essentially we are integrating on it the function $f(x,y)\cdot 1_{D_1\sqcup D_2}$. We then try to write integral on each part as a multiple integral.

Comment: ah ok, i understand whar you mean with rectangle. Then for  $D_2$: $\int_{D_s}f(x,y)dydx = \int_1^\infty \Big( \int_{-\infty}^x f(x,y) dy \Big)dx$ ?

Comment: Not exactly, the boundaries of $y$ there do not depend on $x$. I have written a longer answer, see if you're okay with that.

Comment: what the intuition behind choosing the sets the way you have done? Are there any alternative or is this the only right solution?

Comment: First of all this is not the only correct solution, but the one that sprang to my mind. If you'll see look at the set $D_1 \cup D_2$, then you could similarly decompose it into other 'rectangles' $\{(x,y):  0<y<1, y<x<\infty \}$ and $\{ (x,y):  y\leq 0, x>0 \}$.

Answer (score 0):

Note that $x > 0$ and $y < 1$ can only satisfy $x > y$ on the interval $(0, 1)$.

We can choose $x$ arbitrarily on the interval $(0, 1)$.

We must have $y$ varying from $0$ to $x$ (so that the inequality $x > y$ is satisfied!).

Thus,

$$P(X > Y) = \int_{0}^{x}\int_{0}^{1} f(x, y) \mathop{dx} \mathop{dy}. $$

Alternatively, we can have $y$ vary arbitrarily, and we can have $x$ vary from $y$ to $1$.

Therefore,

$$P(X >Y) = \int_{y}^{1} \int_{0}^{1} f(x, y) \mathop{dy} \mathop{dx} $$